# "string:" is appended to the values of an object in ng-options, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have the following select element:

```
            <select id="room_id_free_round_select" ng-model="generatePostKeys.freeRoundsRoomId" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in generatePostKeys.freeRoundsRoomIdsObj" class="form-control">
        </select>
```

`freeRoundsRoomIdsObj` is object that contains the following:

```
{11: "11 - Niagara Falls",
 12: "12 - Mount Rushmore",
 13: "13 - Yellowstone Park"}
```

the html select is populated with the following options:

```
<select id="room_id_free_round_select" ng-model="generatePostKeys.freeRoundsRoomId" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in generatePostKeys.freeRoundsRoomIdsObj" class="form-control ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style="">
<option label="11 - Niagara Falls" value="string:11">11 - Niagara Falls</option>
<option label="12 - Mount Rushmore" value="string:12">12 - Mount Rushmore</option>
<option label="13 - Yellowstone Park" value="string:13">13 - Yellowstone Park</option>
```

as you can see it happends `string:` to the value. why?!? how can i stop angular from doing that ?

Comment: @MartijnWelker - thanks